# how to get all the div in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="web_index">
<div style="display:block" >content 1</div>
<div style="display:none">content 2</div>
<div style="display:none">content 3</div>
</div>
```

i used

```
 var div =document.getElementsByClass("web_index").getElementsByTagName("div");
```

it tips me there `TypeError: document.getElementsByClass is not a function`.why, and how to get all the `div` in the `web_index` div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
var div =document.getElementsByClassName("web_index")[0].getElementsByTagName("div");
```

`getElementsByClassName` does not exist in some Internet Explorer versions and maybe you need to create that function:

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) {
  var retnode = [];
  var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if((' ' + elem[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cl + ' ') > -1) retnode.push(elem[i]);
  }
  return retnode;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `document.getElementsByClassName` not `document.getElementsByClass`.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("web_index").getElementsByTagName is not a function

Answer (score 1):

As it says there is not such a function "getElementsByClass". What you can do is get all "div" and loop through it comparing elements className with "web_index".

Answer (score 0):

[by classname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

Answer (score 0):

its

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('web_index').getElementsByTagName("div");
```

or you could use javascript `querySelector()` function

```
var div = document.querySelector('.web_index').getElementsByTagName("div");
```